# disable and enable all controls in winforms using mvvm on a button click which is in view

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, data-binding

I am having a mvvm basic app which has two propereties name and address , On the view I had made two textboxes which are binded to these properties respectively .
What I need to do is I will be having a disable/enable button on view if clicked it will disable all the other controls on the form and if again clicked it will enable all the other controls on form .

MVVM is mostly best with WPF but I need to do it with MVVM + winforms , any leads will be highly appreciated .
I need to do it by writing minimum code in view because with view it is a cakewalk just iterating through controls and disabling it on button click .I need some help to do this via some changes in viewmodel only .

Viewmodel -

```
    internal class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    PersonModel personModel;
    private readonly DataTable viewModelDatable;
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        personModel = new PersonModel();
        viewModelDatable = personModel.fillAndGetDataInDataTable();

    }  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {`enter code here`
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {                
             return viewModelDatable.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {                
            viewModelDatable.Rows[0]["Name"] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get { return viewModelDatable.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString(); }
        set
        {
            viewModelDatable.Rows[0]["Address"] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }
    public string NameAndAddress
    {
        get
        {

            if (( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))  &&  (Address  && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Address)))
               return Name +" " + Constants.validNameAndAddress + " "  + Address;
            else if ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name)) && ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Address)))
                return  Constants.noName;
            else if (( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Address)) && ( && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name)))
                return  Constants.noAddress;

            return Constants.noInput;
        }         
    }
    public void saveDataToViewModel()
    {
        personModel.GetDataFromViewModel(viewModelDatable);            
    }
    public void ResetData()
    {
        Name = "";
        Address = "";      
    }

}
```

Model -

```
    internal  class PersonModel
{
    DataTable modelDataTable;


    public DataTable fillAndGetDataInDataTable()
    {
        modelDataTable = new DataTable();
        modelDataTable.enter code hereClear();
        modelDataTable.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
        modelDataTable.Col`enter code here`umns.Add("Address");
        DataRow row = modelDataTable.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = "";  
        row["Address"] = "";
        modelDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        return modelDataTable;
    }

    public void GetDataFromViewModel(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        modelDataTable = dataTable;
    }
}
```

View-

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PersonViewModel personViewModel;
    public Form1()
    {
        personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = personViewModel ;
    }


    private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personViewModel.saveDataToViewModel();
    }

    private void btnReset_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personViewModel.ResetData();
    }
```

}

Comment: please share some thoughts or leads through which problem like this can be addressed .

Comment: Just do it in the very same way you would do in WPF (MVVM works exactly the same in both): Put a boolean property on the viewmodel, bind that to the `Enabled` property of all controls, and when the button is clicked a method on the viewmodel will be called switching the value of the flag and raising a change notification.